# display 2 cardlayout panel simultaneously after one another

Tags: java, swing, thread-sleep, cardlayout

I want to display 2 cardlayout, the first one will be displayed then after some delay the second one will be displayed. I tried my code but It will skip the first one and directly display the second one.

```
CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout)mainpanel.getLayout();
cardLayout.show(mainpanel, "card10");

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);
cardLayout.show(mainpanel, "card11");
```

Comment: Search on Java Swing `Thread.sleep(...)`, and then you'll see why it's poisoning your code. Question closed as a duplicate (one of **many**). The duplicate will give you the solution -- use a Swing Timer.

Comment: thanks! I had some trouble wording the question thus when i searched on google what I found where not related to what I needed.

Comment: [This would be a better Google search on this problem](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+swing+thread+sleep+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)